# Socket gets Closed after 1st command

Tags: java, sockets, networking, ftp

am making a simple ftp client/server program which on command from the clients lists files, tells the current directory, downloads files.

I want to create a server which is able to be connect with multiple clients and is capable of handling multiple commands at a time. I have used threading but my code gives the following error after the 1st command is executed.

```
socket closed
at java.net.SocketInputStream.socketRead0(Native Method)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.DataInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.readBytes(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.implRead(Unknown Source)
at sun.nio.cs.StreamDecoder.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.InputStreamReader.read(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.fill(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at java.io.BufferedReader.readLine(Unknown Source)
at Myserver$Connecthandle.run(Myserver.java:123)
at Myserver.main(Myserver.java:35)
java.net.SocketException: socket closed
```

Here's my server code:

```
public class Myserver {
static final int PortNumber = 120;
static ServerSocket MyService;
static Socket clientSocket = null;
/**
 * @param args
 * @throws IOException 
 */
public static void main(String[] args) throws IOException {
    File directory;
    directory = new File(System.getProperty("user.dir"));
     try {
           MyService = new ServerSocket(PortNumber);
           String cd = directory.toString();
           System.out.println(cd);
           System.out.println("Listening on " + PortNumber);
           while(true) {
           clientSocket = MyService.accept();
           Connecthandle a = new Connecthandle(clientSocket, directory);
           a.start();
           }
     }
     catch (IOException e) {
     System.out.println(e);
     }
}

     static class Connecthandle extends Thread {
         File Directory;
         Socket clientsocket;
         PrintWriter outgoing;

         // Constructor for class
         Connecthandle(Socket clients, File dir) {
             clientsocket = clients;
             Directory = dir;
         }

         // Works Fine
         void listfiles() throws IOException {
             String []Listfile = Directory.list();
             String send = "";
             for (int j = 0; j < Listfile.length; j++) {
                 send = send + Listfile[j] + ",";
             }
             DataOutputStream GoingOut = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
             GoingOut.writeBytes(send);
             GoingOut.flush();
             // GoingOut.close();
         }
         // Works Fine
         void currentdirectory() throws IOException {
             String cd = Directory.toString();
             String cdd = "resp," + cd;
             System.out.println(cdd);
             DataOutputStream GoingOut = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
             GoingOut.writeBytes(cdd);
             GoingOut.flush();
             GoingOut.close();
         }

         // Works fine
         void sendfiles(String fileName) {
             try {
             File nfile = new File(fileName);
             DataOutputStream GoingOut = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
             if ( (! nfile.exists()) || nfile.isDirectory() ) {
               GoingOut.writeBytes("file not present");
            } else {
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nfile));
             int coun = 0;
             String lin;
             while ((lin = br.readLine()) != null) {
                 coun++;
             }
             GoingOut.writeBytes("resp," + fileName + "," + String.valueOf(coun) + "\n");
             @SuppressWarnings("resource")
            BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nfile));
             String line;
             while ((line = sr.readLine()) != null) {
                 GoingOut.writeBytes(line+"\n");
                 GoingOut.flush();
             }
             GoingOut.close();
             br.close();
            }
             } catch (IOException e) {
                 System.out.println("Unable to send!");
             }
         }

         public void start() {
             DataInputStream comingin = null;
            try {
                comingin = new DataInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
             InputStreamReader isr = null;
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(comingin, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
             while (true) {
             try {
             String message = br.readLine(); 
             if (message.contains("pwd")) {
                 currentdirectory();
             } else if (message.contains("list")) {
                 listfiles();
             } else if (message.contains("get")) {
                 String fileName = new String(message.substring(8, message.length()));
                 sendfiles(fileName);
             } else if (message.contains("exit")) {
                 System.exit(0);
             }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } finally {
                 try {
                    clientsocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
             }
         }
     }
```

}
I moved all the methods into start() so i only needed to declare dataoutputstream once but now it gives a NULLPOINTEREXCEPTION whenever i use Outgoing.writeBytes

Updated:

```
    static class Connecthandle extends Thread {
         File Directory;
         Socket clientsocket;
         PrintWriter outgoing;

         // Constructor for class
         Connecthandle(Socket clients, File dir) {
             clientsocket = clients;
             Directory = dir;
         }

         public void run() {
             DataInputStream comingin = null;
            try {
                comingin = new DataInputStream(clientsocket.getInputStream());
            } catch (IOException e2) {
                e2.printStackTrace();
            }
             InputStreamReader isr = null;
            try {
                isr = new InputStreamReader(comingin, "UTF-8");
            } catch (UnsupportedEncodingException e1) {
                e1.printStackTrace();
            }
             BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(isr);
             while (true) {
             try {
             String message = br.readLine(); 
             if (message.contains("pwd")) {
                 String cd = Directory.toString();
                 String cdd = "resp," + cd;
                 System.out.println(cdd);
                 DataOutputStream GoingOut = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
                 GoingOut.writeBytes(cdd);
                 GoingOut.flush();
             } else if (message.contains("list")) {
                 String []Listfile = Directory.list();
                 String send = "";
                 for (int j = 0; j < Listfile.length; j++) {
                     send = send + Listfile[j] + ",";
                 }
                 DataOutputStream GoingOut = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
                 GoingOut.writeBytes(send);
                 GoingOut.flush();
             } else if (message.contains("get")) {
                 String fileName = new String(message.substring(8, message.length()));
                 try {
                     File nfile = new File(fileName);
                     DataOutputStream GoingOut = new DataOutputStream(clientsocket.getOutputStream());
                     if ( (! nfile.exists()) || nfile.isDirectory() ) {
                       GoingOut.writeBytes("file not present");
                    } else {
                     BufferedReader wr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nfile));
                     int coun = 0;
                     String lin;
                     while ((lin = wr.readLine()) != null) {
                         coun++;
                     }
                     GoingOut.writeBytes("resp," + fileName + "," + String.valueOf(coun) + "\n");
                     @SuppressWarnings("resource")
                    BufferedReader sr = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(nfile));
                     String line;
                     while ((line = sr.readLine()) != null) {
                         GoingOut.writeBytes(line+"\n");
                         GoingOut.flush();
                     }
                     GoingOut.close();
                     br.close();
             } 
                 } catch (IOException e) {
                     System.out.println("Unable to send!"); 
                 }
             } else if (message.contains("exit")) {
                 System.exit(0);
             }
             } catch (Exception e) {
                 e.printStackTrace();
             } finally {
                 try {
                    clientsocket.close();
                } catch (IOException e) {
                    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
             }
             }
         }
     }
}
```

Comment: Aren't you closing the socket after the first command?

Comment: Can you please tell me where? and how i can avoid it?

Comment: `clientsocket.close();` in your finally block...  Also I'm not 100%, but closing a stream you get from the socket may close the socket also...

Comment: I moved the finally block out of the loop but that didn't help. What i believe is happening is that my DataOutputStream in sendfiles, listfiles and current directory gets closed after calling the function which inturn closes the socket as well but if i don't close my outputstream then my code just hangs.

Comment: I also tried removing the methods and putting the entire thing in start() because of which i had to declare GoingOut only once but then my code gave a NullPointerException on the line GoingOut.writeBytes(send);

Comment: Please update your question to show the latest code you are using.

Comment: updated code for reference

Answer (score 0):

Closing the input stream or output stream of a socket closes the other stream and the socket. I don't see why you need to close anything here until the client disconnects or you time him out.